# How to write a Python 3 script to do .\activate in Windows 10 OS?

Tags: windows, shell, python-3.6

I'm trying to write a script to activate the virtual environment under a path, which is doing the same thing as the following command line:

```
cd C:\go\to\my\venv\path\Scripts
.\activate
```

My idea is first to change the directory to my Scripts folder, then execute the .\activate file. The problem is I have tried
1. `os.system(".\\activate")  #".\activate" is an error`
2. `subprocess.run(".\\activate")`
3. `subprocess.call(".\\activate")`
4. `subprocess.Popen(".\\activate", shell=True)`

but all failed, and because I'm new to Python 3, so any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks.

Update 1:
Right now, it seems like can install one package successfully, but I have a list of packages need to install and I will figure it out how to do it. When I print out os.getcwd() after I activated the venv, there is no (venv) as the prefix in the result, so I don't know if the package was installed under venv or not?

Update 2:
Now, my problem is I'm using from pip._internal import main as pip

pip(['install', package_name])
It only can install one package successfully, if I pass a list of packages and use for loop to install them then they will fail. The error will be

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\BO7D71~1.CHE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-1nc0ofuc\5fc2bc8999692b42fb54fd13e7cbdf5f855b9718f5363d30a270bbe1'

Update 3:
Problem solved!

Comment: No, I don't want the user to do anything, basically, I'm doing dependencies checking and reinstalling the missing dependencies for a project, so which means there is no user interacts, I want to reinstall some missing dependencies automatically if I can activate the virtual environment.

Comment: and also I tried .\activate.bat in the command prompt, it was wrong, only .\activate can activate the virtual environment then I can use "pip install tensorflow-hub" for example to install this library successfully.

Comment: Yes, I was using the PowerShell to do all the testing such as change directory, activate/deactivate virtual environment, install/uninstall libraries. So, I want to implement a python script to do the same thing just as what I have done in the PowerShell.

Comment: @Tristo, thank you for your editing, this is exactly what I wanted. Even I tried to type as your style but It appeared differently and I don't know to modify it.

Comment: You'll need a command line that's something like `args = ';'.join([r"& 'C:\go\to\my\venv\path\Scripts\activate.ps1'", r'other command', r'another command'])` and then run it via `subprocess.call(r'powershell -command {}'.format(args))`. You'll have to handle escaping PowerShell's special characters in the command line.

Comment: hmm, still a little bit confused, the activate.ps1 does exist in the folder, but I only tried .\activate so I don't know if this works. But I will try to implement your suggestion tomorrow and thank you for your reply and when I try if I meet another problem and I will let you know, peace.

Comment: Update the question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: "pip.exe" in the "Scripts" directory has an embedded script with a shebang that executes the fully-qualified path of the virtual environment's "python.exe". You can run this command explicitly, i.e. `r"C:\go\to\my\venv\path\Scripts\pip.exe"`, without having to activate the environment for interactive use.

Comment: When you say "os.getcwd() after I activated the venv, there is no (venv) as the prefix", you're confusing the interactive shell `PROMPT`, which often includes the value of the working directory, with the process working directory. `os.getcwd()` returns the file-system path that's set as the working directory of the process.